# How to vectorise numerical differentiation

Tags: finite-difference, matrix, differential-equations

I have a 2-D matrix with 2 spatial coordinates and I want to be able to vectorise the process of numerically differentiating with respect to its 2 coordinates, rather than just looping along the rows and columns. On page 307 of [this](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/ijnam/Volume-7-2010/No-2-10/2010-02-06.pdf), they have the equations:

(2.9a) $\quad f^{\prime}\left(x_i\right) \approx \alpha_{i,-2} f\left(x_{i-2}\right)+\alpha_{i,-1} f\left(x_{i-1}\right)+\alpha_{i, 0} f\left(x_i\right)$,
$(2.9 \mathrm{~b}) \quad f^{\prime}\left(x_i\right) \approx \beta_{i,-1} f\left(x_{i-1}\right)+\beta_{i, 0} f\left(x_i\right)+\beta_{i, 1} f\left(x_{i+1}\right)$,
$(2.9 \mathrm{c}) \quad f^{\prime}\left(x_i\right) \approx \gamma_{i, 0} f\left(x_i\right)+\gamma_{i, 1} f\left(x_{i+1}\right)+\gamma_{i, 2} f\left(x_{i+2}\right)$,

$$
\begin{gathered}
\alpha_{i,-2}=\frac{\Delta x_i}{\Delta x_{i-1}\left(\Delta x_{i-1}+\Delta x_i\right)}, \alpha_{i,-1}=\frac{-\Delta x_{i-1}-\Delta x_i}{\Delta x_{i-1} \Delta x_i}, \alpha_{i, 0}=\frac{\Delta x_{i-1}+2 \Delta x_i}{\Delta x_i\left(\Delta x_{i-1}+\Delta x_i\right)} \\
\beta_{i,-1}=\frac{-\Delta x_{i+1}}{\Delta x_i\left(\Delta x_i+\Delta x_{i+1}\right)}, \beta_{i, 0}=\frac{\Delta x_{i+1}-\Delta x_i}{\Delta x_i \Delta x_{i+1}}, \beta_{i, 1}=\frac{\Delta x_i}{\Delta x_{i+1}\left(\Delta x_i+\Delta x_{i+1}\right)}, \\
\gamma_{i, 0}=\frac{-2 \Delta x_{i+1}-\Delta x_{i+2}}{\Delta x_{i+1}\left(\Delta x_{i+1}+\Delta x_{i+2}\right)}, \quad \gamma_{i, 1}=\frac{\Delta x_{i+1}+\Delta x_{i+2}}{\Delta x_{i+1} \Delta x_{i+2}}, \gamma_{i, 2}=\frac{-\Delta x_{i+1}}{\Delta x_{i+2}\left(\Delta x_{i+1}+\Delta x_{i+2}\right)} .
\end{gathered}
$$

But how would I implement this computationally? If my $\mathbf{U}$ is $m\times n$ matrix with spatial coordinates $(x_i,y_i)$ and I want to take the first derivative of $x$ by doing something like, $\mathbf{D_x} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{U’}$, how would I do that?

My first thought is that we have the $\mathbf{D_x}$ matrix to be tri-diagonal with entries like $\beta$ and then $\gamma$ and $\alpha$ entries on the boundaries, but then how would $\mathbf{U'}$ $(x_i , y_i)$ at the $x_i$ position use the $\mathbf{U} $ $(x_{i+1} ,y_i)$ at the $x_{i+1}$ position? In other words, how can you setup $D_x$ such that it uses $\mathbf{U}$ $(x_{i+1} ,y_i)$ and $\mathbf{U}(x_{i-1},y_i)$ to find $\mathbf{U’}(x_i,y_i)$

Comment: It is worth noting that looping over the elements will be faster than a naive matrix implementation. You will need to use sparse matrix multiplication to get any speedup

Comment: Yes, but it depends on the language used. Anyway, I think it is best to avoid having to deal with a matrix at all, let alone form this matrix. I would rather directly form the vector of the residuals (or RHS, i.e. $DU$). This can usually be done in a vectorised fashion more easily in languages which are slow wrt for loops (e.g. Python with Numpy).

Comment: @Laurent90 that is what I’m affectively asking. I would be using a sparse matrix. I’ve seen it before but am not too familiar with it, hence the question. What’s the key word for the type of operation so I can read about it?

Comment: Well, ADI schemes need the Jacobian $D$ (which is e.g. pentadiagonal and thus makes it easy to solve linear problems of the form $DU=b$. If your only trying to compute $DU$ for a given $U$, then $D$ does not always need to be formed. You simply need to code directly the equations you have given. See for example in Python https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vectorized-operations-in-numpy/. For compiled languages such as C or Fortran, for loops are usually as efficient as vectorised calls.

Comment: I think, you are stuck with the dimensions of U and spatial dimension of the mesh x. When going from 1D to n-D you need to bijectively identify each coordinate pair of your mesh with a global index of the pair and a unique index for X.  With this equipped you can vectorize U gain, since you have a well defined order, can can setup Dx accordingly to the index, e.g. [see chapter 6.10](https://depts.washington.edu/ph506/Boyd.pdf) .